# Can't record nebula objects using rcptt

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nebula, eclipse-rcptt

i'm trying to record a test over a rcp app but i can't; the nebula object can't be recorded by rcptt tool. I am using rcptt version 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Like all RCP testing tools, RCPTT also can not record actions on Nebula controllers.

The reason for that is Nebula goes around SWT's API and renders controllers in a more resource aware way.

Comment: ok, perfect then i will think in change the nebula control by other than i can use with rcptt. Regards.

Comment: It is not a good idea to change your product because of an inadequate testing tool. Maybe Nebula controls were chosen because of performance reasons. Instead find other ways to test their content; for example logging their raw data or creating debugging-controllers for the same data.